# Form Submit Button Do not work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with a submit button. Unfortunately my javascript function does not work. Where is my mistake? It works by pressing enter but not by clicking on the submit button

```
<div id="form" class="contact-us-form">
    <form id="myform" target="_self" onsubmit="" action="javascript: postContactToGoogle()">
        <div>
            <input spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" id="email" type="text" name="email" value="deine eMail" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="this.value='deine eMail'">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button onclick="submits()" id="send" type="submit">EINTRAGEN</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submits() {
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();

    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your function "postContactToGoogle()" implemented some where in your page??

Comment: First, you don't need the onclick action or the submits() function because it is already a Submit button.  Next, where is your postContactToGoogle() function?

Comment: Yes, this function is implemented in the page, why? It works by pressing enter but not by clicking on the submit button.

Comment: @felixgerlach because it does not works that way... the enter key triggers the submit of the form (a form event) and not the click on a button (a button event). since the button is an input control the click on it automatically triggers the form event, no need for a redundant and useless 'onclick' handler

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is strange. You are trying to do the submission very "manually". The submit button (i.e. the type="submit" part) is already going to submit this form, so there is no need for your function submits().

Afterwards, in javascript, simply refer to your form's submit event. You can get the form by id like your doing already.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'name' attribute in your form

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <!-- Form content -->
</form>
```

change your script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submits() {
        document.myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake by myself:

```
onblur="this.value='deine eMail'"
```

Do not use onblur in your submit button. It will kill the submit function and it will not work